# Eclipse PDE :: Startup

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, startup

What happens first when an Eclipse application is launched?

I'm particularly interested in

- the interplay of OSGi bundles and Eclipse plug-ins
- the order of execution
- XML parsing of plug-in definitions and their implications
- the entry point of the whole undertaking

Comment: Sorry but this is way too broad for Stack Overflow. `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main` contains the `main` method.

Comment: Have you tried enabling the respective tracing options? Those should give you some more pointers to look into.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann: Thank you for the hint! The only traces I could conceive of are the one in the debugger and the error trace in the console. Are there any more?

Comment: If you run the Eclipse application from the IDE, the launch configuration dialog has a Tracing tab where you can enable tracing options for components you are interested in.